# PageMethods not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

I have a page with a MasterPage, in the master page, I have this:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptManager" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   AsyncPostBackTimeout="99999999"
                                   EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

And I have this method in the code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SavePreference(string graphVersion)
{
    //some code here
}
```

And then I have this javascript function:

```
 function lnkLearnHardWayclick(){ 
    if( $("#chkDontShowAgain").attr("checked") == "checked")
    {
        PageMethods.SavePreference('new');
    }
    $("#info").hide();
    $("#hardWay").show();
}
```

But when I click on the link to make everything work, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PageMethods` are not supported in master pages and user controls.

Comment: I don't understand it... so I have to put the ToolScriptManager in the page i want to do the PageMethods?? Because all the code of the Javascript and the code behind y have it in example.aspx (for isntance).

Comment: put your pagemethod in to the `.aspx.cs` file.

Comment: Yes, I Have it here... in fact, one partener of my job did in another page and worked... I don't know why it doesn't work to me

Comment: Well... it was that the WebMethod have to be static hehe. Thanks anyways!