# How to call code behind method from a javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, scriptmanager

I am having an javascript function for a HTML img click event in aspx page. And a server Method in its code behind page.Now I want to call the server method from the javascript function without any parameter only when the HTML img is clicked by the user.

C# Code Behind Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void PopUpClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Something;
}
```

JavaScriptMethod:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.clickme').click(function () {
        PageMethods.PopUpClick();
    });

});
```

Also I added into the master page: `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" />`

It is not working.When I debugging this Javascript function on the Chrome 
I saw an error:Uncaught Reference Error:PageMethods is not defined.

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662592/calling-code-behind-from-javascript

Comment: You want to look into AJAX sir

Comment: just make it a static method it might work

Answer (score 6):

**.aspx**

```
     <div>
        <p>Say bye-bey to Postbacks.</p>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Signup" OnClientClick="HandleIT(); return false;" />
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function HandleIT() {
            var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtname.ClientID %>').value;
            var address = document.getElementById('<%=txtaddress.ClientID %>').value;
            PageMethods.ProcessIT(name, address, onSucess, onError); 
            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something wrong.');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**C#**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string ProcessIT(string name, string address)
    {
        string result = "Welcome Mr. " + name + ". Your address is '" + address + "'.";
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful, even two years later, almost to the day!

Answer (score 2):

The WebMethods that are defined must be "static".

The following ajax call to a WebMethod "GetAllRegions" works fine, provided, the WebMethod is defined as static!!

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'GenerateEAInHtml.aspx/GetAllRegions',
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
});
```

The WebMethod is defined this way:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Region> GetAllRegions()
{
  /* Your Code goes here */
  return regions;
}
```

You might want to use this Ajax Post to also pass JSON data to the WebMethod by passing the data parameter!! This should help.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption that your page name is abc.aspx and xyz is the function name that you have to call.
javascript :

```
function sendData(offset) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "abc.aspx/xyz",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Server Side : add **Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization**

```
WebMethod(enableSession:=True) _
Public Shared Function xyz() As String
    your code here
End Function
```

Add module in web.config -> system.webServer

```
->system.webServer>
    ->modules>
    ->add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    ->/modules>
->/system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Back end C# code is separate from your front end JavaScript code. JS runs on the client side and C# runs server side. In order to have front end code fire off a back end functions, you would either need your function to do a form postback or use Ajax (or an equivalent) to call that pages function.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx). The handler does not need to be tagged as `[WebMethod]`

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnPopUp" ImageUrl="img.png" OnClick="PopUpClick" />
```

Why do you want to use img directly?

Comment: because I have to creating of this image in code behind into a method like this. return "<span style='color:red;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;'>....</span><img style='width:112px; heigh:37px' src='...' class='clickme' />";

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[WebMethod]

  public static void PopUpClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Something;
    }
```

Comment: Try what? You have just posted part of the OP's code, which they already have

Comment: No, it's not the same. Keep a close look. ;)

Comment: OK, so you have made it `static`, how is that going to help?

Comment: That could be a probable solution for the error "Uncaught Reference Error:PageMethods is not defined."

Comment: I can't using static because the page and some variable in the methods  are not static.

Comment: This won't fix that problem. The error shown is a javascript error, you wont fix that by making a code behind method static

Comment: @user2729114 : Some common useful tips 1.The page method must have the System.Web.Services.WebMethod attribute. [WebMethod]
2.The page method must be public. [WebMethod] public ...
3.The page method must be static. [WebMethod] public static ...
4.The page method must be defined on the page (either inline or in the code-behind). It cannot be defined in a control, master page, or base page.
5.The ASP.NET AJAX Script Manager must have EnablePageMethods set to true.

Comment: @TapasMahata: If all that is true, then why don't you make that part of your answer. Then I will remove my downvote

Comment: @musefan: please have a look on this similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188291/pagemethods-not-defined

Comment: @TapasMahata: Why? How does that make your answer any better?

Answer (score 0):

There is a line at the top that says uncomment this to call it by JavaScript.

Uncomment that.

Then also add a `[ScriptMethod]` to your method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public void PopUpClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Something;
}
```

You should then be able to call it from the `PageMethods` object.

However I've just done some research and it seems that you may need to place your code that uses `PageMethods` at the end / after the `ScriptManager` as its possible you are trying to use `PageMethods` before its been declared in the JavaScript. Alternatively if you're using jQuery then you can do it in the `ready` event so you know the page and everything has loaded. I think this will probably turn out to be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

A web method has to be declared as static and public.

Although you can't access the page directly, you can either pass what you need into the web method from the call in your client side code, or store what you need in session or a similar state storage mechanism that is accessible from your static web method.

That may require re-thinking what you're trying to do with it.