# Calling Code behind Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to call function through javascript, but I get an error message
"CS0103: The name 'bidindex' does not exist in the current context"
Can you help me? Thanks

**JS code**

```
<script>
    function senddata(whatdate, bidindex) {          
        var a = "<%=DatabidGridView1(bidindex,whatdate%>";
    }
</script>
```

**.cs code**

```
public string DatabidGridView1(string sindex, string sdate)
        {
   return "good";
        }
```

Comment: needs to be a static WebMethod, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510749/how-to-call-code-behind-method-from-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

Like [homungus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3524076/homungus) said the Method in your codebehind has to be a static WebMethod.

It could be something like:

**JS Code**

```
$(".clickMe").click(function(){ senddata(data, index) });

function senddata(whatdate, bidindex) {          
   PageMethods.DatabidGridView1(bidindex, whatdate);
}
```

**.CS Code**

```
[WebMethod]
public string DatabidGridView1(string sindex, string sdate)
{return "good";}
```

Also meby a useful link with useful information: [Pagemethods in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313532/pagemethods-in-asp-net)